# Getting a model's children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

If I have a model, ie. User, and each user has_many :animals, how do I get a retrieve the list of all of a particular set of User's animals?

I'd like to do something like this:

```
a = User.where(:last_name => 'Statham').animals
```

and have a be a list of the Animal objects. I assume I'm missing something trivial and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, simple is right. You're getting a lot of users there, so you need to iterate through them.

```
stathams = User.where(:last_name => 'Statham')
stathams.each { |statham| statham.animals }
```

And if you want to avoid duplicates:

```
animals = []
stathams = User.where(:last_name => 'Statham')
stathams.each { |statham| animals << statham.animals }
animals.uniq!
```

Comment: I get that, for the first user - but what if I wanted ALL of the animals belonging to a number of users? Ie. I want a list the animals that belongs to Users whose first name is 'John'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Animal.where(user_id: User.where(last_name: "Statham"))
```